# How to avoid navigation bar overlay on the video seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar, navigationbar, android-fullscreen

I have a video activity with title at the top and `SeekBar` with media controls at the bottom. Both the title and `SeekBar` layouts overlay on the `SurfaceView` when a touch event is fired and they disappear after a certain time. I'm also implementing Immersive mode where both the status and navigation bars disappear along with the title and `SeekBar`. I have managed to make space for the status bar to appear without overlaying on the title layout using the below attribute.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

But if I use the same attribute for my media controls layout at the bottom of the screen it doesn't work. As a result the navigation bar is overlaid on the layout. I couldn't figure out why the above attribute is working fine on one layout and not on the other. I have a customized layout for the media controls, I have a class that extends `FrameLayout`. Does the attribute `fitSystemWindows` doesn't work for customized layouts? See the icon at the bottom right in the first screen-shot. It is getting overlaid by the navigation bar as shown in the second screen-shot

[image]

[image]

I have included part of my class file and layout below.

**MediaController.java**

```
public class MediaController extends FrameLayout {

    //Some private fields are declared here

    public MediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward, boolean useFullScreenButton) {
        super(context);
        ....
    }

    public MediaController(Context context) {
        this(context, true, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        if (mRoot != null)
            initControllerView(mRoot);
    }

    //Inflating the layout here
    protected View makeControllerView() {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);
        ....
        return mRoot;
    }

    //Lot of other methods here

}
```

**media_controller.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> <!--Using the attribute here-->

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/time_current"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="32dip" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to share a short video (or a screenshot) with the problem and then explain how it should work.

Comment: @Nactus I've added the screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: "See the icon at the bottom right in the first screen-shot. It is getting overlaid by the navigation bar as shown in the second screen-shot", so if I get you correctly you'd like to hide the navigation bar when your media-player is active, correct? (the first picture is how it should look and the second picture is what you get, correct?)

Comment: I could hide it but when I touch the screen I get what you could see in the 2nd picture. The only thing I don't want is the navigation bar to be overlaid on the bottom right icon. The icon should move left of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the nav-bar hide it like this:

```
// onResume ensures that every time the application is resumed, the nav bar goes away
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        //int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Also, check this out:

> > On Android 4.1 and higher, you can set your application's content to appear behind the navigation bar, so that the content doesn't resize
> >     as the navigation bar hides and shows. To do this, use
> >     SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION. You may also need to use
> >     SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE to help your app maintain a stable
> >     layout.
>
> When you use this approach, it becomes your responsibility to ensure
>   that critical parts of your app's UI don't end up getting covered by
>   system bars. For more discussion of this topic, see the Hiding the
>   Status Bar lesson.